# Concatenate excel cell string within cell reference string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am struggling to figure out a way to concatenate a cell value into the format below when referencing to another excel spreadsheets cell value.

Example:
='C:\Test\TestA.xls'!$A$25

I would like to have TestA to be represented, for example, by a cell value within the current excel spreadsheet. Here is what I thought would of worked:

='C:\Test\'+B2+'.xls'!$A$25

Is this possible with this type of formatting?

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the `INDIRECT` function: http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions05.html ; http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/14309-dynamic-file-reference.html

Comment: @NayukiMinase the first link you provided said "An INDIRECT formula can refer to cells in other workbooks, but will return a #REF! error if that workbook is closed. " I need it to work without having the workbook open.

Comment: My gut feeling is that Excel built-in functions like `INDIRECT` have a limitation on how powerful they are. You might need to turn to VBA to accomplish these programming-like features that require essentially unrestrained expressibility.

Comment: You can't refer to another excel sheet and have it work unless that other excel sheet is open.  Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Copied from a Comment by [@Dean MacGregor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1818713/dean-macgregor):

> You can't refer to another Excel sheet and have it work unless that other Excel sheet is open.